# É uma boa ideia inserir arquivos SVG inline?

Tags: html, svg

Estive dando uma passada em uns sites e os que usam logotipos em SVG costumam colocá-los em um arquivo separadamente. Isso traz a praticidade de quando você mudar o arquivo, em todas as páginas ela muda, mas você faz uma requisição a mais.

É uma boa ideia ao invés de chamar a imagem, inserí-la diretamente no HTML? Sobre a praticidade que citei acima, poderia ser facilmente contornada com um arquivo chamado `logotipo-svg.php` (ou `logotipo-svg.html`) que gerasse o código SVG inline pronto para ser inserido na página atravéz de um:

```
echo '<div class="logotipo">' . file_get_contents('logotipo-svg.php') . '</div>';
```

É muito trabalho para reduzir os dados transferidos? **A quantidade de dados a serem transferidos é reduzida?**

Comment: Se já tem o arquivo, não é mais simples um `<img src='logotipo.svg'/>` do que processar nos servidor e inserir na página?

Comment: Quero saber se vale a pena não fazer dessa forma, se a quantidade de dados são reduzidos ao cortar essa requisição.

Comment: protip: se for incluir o arquivo no HTML, e ele for um arquivo estático, copie e cole ele direto no HTML. É desnecessário usar `file_get_contents`, aka overenginering :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Casos aonde fortemente NÃO tem boa performance fazer isso**

1. O site já usa um sprite, aonde muitas imagens pequenas são carregadas de uma vez
2. O logo é uma fonte de texto (semelhante ao que ocorre com sprite
3. Sua imagem é grande

**Casos aonde tende a ser interessante fazer isso**

1. Sua imagem é pequena. (talvez 1~3kb), qualquer tipo de imagem.
2. Tamanho não muito grande (talvez 10~50kb?), se a imagem não se repetir em mais páginas, e não for SVG (JPEG, PNG e GIF inline em base64 aumentam muito o tamanho)
3. Qualquer tamanho, se a imagem não se repete em mais páginas e for SVG (compressão do SVG dentro e fora do HTML será equivalente)

*Estudo de caso: Site http://alligo.com.br/, página única, inclui imagem no HTML com `<img src="data:..` carrega mais rápido com PNG inline do que se estivesse como externo. *

**Aonde você obrigatóriamente vai incluir no HTML um SVG**

1. Seu SVG é criado e manipulado por Javascript

*Estudo de caso: gráficos gerados em http://atlas.sies.org.br/ são criados com Javascript.*

Disclaimer: Os dois sites de exemplo foram feitos pelo pelo autor dessa resposta.